# how to use struct define in another class

Tags: c++, structure

I have class which looks like

```
struct Games
{ char Name[80];
char Rating;
bool  Played;
long NumberOfKills;
} Unreal, Blizzard[3];

typedef Games* Gamesptr;

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    int x;
    Gamesptr  ptr =  new Games;
    return 0;
}
```

Now i want to use the struct defined above in another class like below

```
structTest::structTest(void)
{
}

structTest::~structTest(void)
{
}
void structTest::test(void)
{
    // goes here        
    Games *structptr = new Games;// This not working ....
}
```

how do i do this ..when I tried it throws me ' no appropriate default constructor available' error...

Comment: 'for exammple struct Games' - This sounds confusing

Comment: whats confusing .. I want to use the structure  in another class .how do i do that ...straightforward is it ??

Answer (score 2):

It looks like your `struct Games` is declared in one file, and `structTest` in another file. Is that right?

Your `structTest` class needs to see the definition of the `Games` struct in order to work.

Put the `Games` struct in its own file (maybe call it `Games.h`). `#include` this in the file that includes your `main` function and in the file that defines the `structTest` class.

Note that `Unreal` and `Blizzard[3]` still need to be in the file that includes your `main` function, not in the header file, which should contain only the `struct` definition (and optionally the `typedef` if you plan to use that in other modules).

Answer (score 1):

I think you should improve your formatting, because even at this moment *it has already become hard to read.* I can hardly ever think of what might happen at the following stages of your project.

**Now - directly to the question.**

I think you want to have the following:

```
struct Games {
   // whatever
   bool value;
};

struct GamesHolder {
   Games games;
};
```

Now, if the `Games` isn't just a raw data holder, but stands for some kind of the abstraction or holds a too much data to be placed on the stack, *you might want to use the following pattern:*

```
struct GamesHolder {
   Games* games_pointer;
};
```

The initialization now may be implemented the following way:

```
GamesHolder games_holder;
games_holder.games_pointer = new Games(...whatever);

// If the memory is not cleared when the 'games_holder'
// leaves the scope - bang - a memory leak.
```

As long as sometimes manual memory management becomes a pain in the *ss, you also might want to start using shared pointers:

```
struct GamesHolder {
   std::shared_ptr<Games> games_pointer;
}

GamesHolder games_holder;
games_holder.games_pointer.reset(new Games(...));

// No leak if the 'holder' leaves the scope - memory
// is being automatically disposed.
```